# Symmetries of atomic orbitals, s-state forms a triplet!

Tags: atomic-physics, spectroscopy, orbitals

I have a trouble understanding how s-subshell electrons can form a triplet state ever.

In general isn't it true, that there are only two cases for s-state:

1. $\ell=0$, $s=1/2$, $J=1/2$ - doublet (one electron, hydrogen)
2. $\ell=0$, $s=0$, $J=0$ - singlet (two electrons, helium)

So, s-state is always a singlet state when it is not a hydrogen. But how on Earth it can form a triplet? Pauli exclusion principle wouldn't allow two spin-up electrons on s-subshell, no?

Essentially, I reference p.90 of this

http://ist-socrates.berkeley.edu/~phylabs/adv/ReprintsPDF/ATM%20Reprints/02%20-%20Atomic%20Spectra%20and%20Atomic%20Structure.pdf

Answer (score 7):

I actually think I have figured it out: if we consider the situation when the principle quantum number for, let's say, excited helium is different, then we can have spin-up electron in $1S_1$ state and spin-up electron in $2S_1$ state. This is going to be a triplet. Please, correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Seems correct. See [here](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/helium.html).

Comment: Yeah, that's one way. A good way to play around is the [NIST atomic levels database](http://physics.nist.gov/PhysRefData/ASD/levels_form.html); for helium it lists exactly those configurations. However, you can also make a triplet $S$ state by combining $p$ orbitals, like e.g. the $1s^22s^22p3p\  ^3S$ state in carbon, which is essentially the superposition $$\frac{ |2,1,1⟩ - |3,1,-1⟩}{\sqrt{2}}$$ in the $|n,l,m_l⟩$ orbital basis, tensored with any triplet spin state. As an exercise, try figuring out the $^3S$ states in oxygen and titanium - NIST provides enough info to piece them together.

Comment: Oh, cool! Thanks a lot for NIST link and for ideas!